# Can't figure out why I can't print the count

Tags: javascript

```
function createCounter(countt) {
  var count = countt
  return {
    increment: function() {
      count = count + 1
      //return console.log(count)
    },

    currentValue: function() {
      return console.log(count)
    }
  }
}

var counterStartingAt5 = createCounter(5)

var counterStartingAtMinus2 = createCounter(-2)
```

Why can't I print the `console.log(count)?` It doesn't work if I use `console.log` on the increment or on the `currentValue`, it just don't print it. It should have access to the count, but for some reason it doesn't return the value... can anyone please explain it?

Comment: because you have never invoked `currentValue`. After `var counterStartingAt5 = createCounter(5)` add this line - `counterStartingAt5.currentValue();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't print anything until you call the `currentValue` function. See the following working example:

```js
function createCounter(countt) {
  var count = countt
  return {
    increment: function() {
      count = count + 1
      //return console.log(count)
    },

    currentValue: function() {
      return console.log(count)
    }
  }
}

var counterStartingAt5 = createCounter(5);
counterStartingAt5.currentValue();
counterStartingAt5.increment();
counterStartingAt5.currentValue();
```

Comment: Oh, I see what it is now... Thanks bro!